# Different placeholder via Javascript on same input ID

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, input

I guess this is pretty basic yet I don't know how to solve this puzzle. What I have is two inputs generated by a plugin in Wordpress. What I want to do is to change the placeholders in the fields.

The problem is that the fields ID (which I use to call the inputs via Javascript) is the same, resulting in that only the first inputs placeholder changes.

The auto-generated HTML:

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Lösenord" name="swpm-19" id="swpm-19" value="" class="swpm-text  swpm-large  required  ">
<input type="password" placeholder="Retype password Here" name="swpm-19_re" id="swpm-19" value="" class="swpm-text  swpm-large  required  ">
```

The Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#swpm-19').attr("placeholder","Lösenord");
    });
</script>
```

I have no idea how to call the second input since the ID's are the same. What I did notice is that the names of the inputs is different. The second inputs name is "swmp-19_re". Would it be possible to fetch the input in the Javascript via the name instead of the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate `id`, this is invalid document.
You can use the attribute value selector to select the elements by using `name` attribute value.

```
$('input[name="swpm-19"], input[name="swpm-19_re"]').attr('placeholder', 'Lösenord');
```

You can also use starts with as

```
$('input[name^="swpm-19"]').attr('placeholder', 'Lösenord');
```

For more information on the type of CSS (attribute) selectors that jQuery supports [check this page](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).